# pandas dataframe data manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframe (df1,df2) with different size. Both has a single column that is the same , column 'code' in df1 and column 'practices' in df2

**df1**

|  | code | name | addr_1 | addr_2 | borough | village | post_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A81002 | QUEENS PARK MEDICAL CENTRE | QUEENS PARK MEDICAL CTR FARRER STREET | STOCKTON ON TEES | CLEVELAND | TS18 2AW |  |
| 1 | A81003 | VICTORIA MEDICAL PRACTICE | THE HEALTH CENTRE VICTORIA ROAD | HARTLEPOOL | CLEVELAND | TS26 8DB |  |

**df2**

|  | practice | bnf_code | bnf_name | items | nic | act_cost | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | N85638 | 0301011R0 | Salamol_Inha 100mcg (200 D) CFF (Teva) | 2 | 2.92 | 2.73 | 2 |
| 1 | N85638 | 0301011R0 | Easyhaler_Salbutamol Sulf 200mcg (200D) | 1 | 6.63 | 6.15 | 1 |

I want to create a new column 'post_code' in df2 using df1 'code' and 'post_code' so that df1 row with same 'code' value as df2 'practice' will have the same post code.

Comment: How will you match rows in df2 with rows in df1?

Comment: take a look at `merge()` and specifically **left_on** and **right_on** parameters.  Your sample data will not produce any thing as code is not common between two DFs

Answer (score 0):

first you need to import packages.
read both datasets.
concatenate the required columns from df1 to df2,
then compare both columns and create new column which represent the value same or not.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1=pd.read_csv("PATH TO DATASET")
df2=pd.read_csv("PATH TO DATASET")
df2=pd.concat([df1["code"],df2],axis=1)
df2["post_code"]=np.where(df2["practice"]==df2["code"],"same","not same")
```

Comment: thanks for your response, will this work if the data frame are of different sizes?

Comment: yes it work under the condition of least size of dataframe fill with NaN value in empty rows,columns,then it wil compare, also it cannnot compare the str and numerical value